# Cannot install compass in Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS 64 bit. Ruby is already installed on

Tags: rubygems, compass-sass

I cannot get compass installed on my Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS. Tried almost everything with no avail.

The last thing I tried was:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby2.0-dev build-essential
sudo gem install compass
```

and got the following:

> Building native extensions.  This could take a while... ERROR:  Error
> installing compass:   ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> ```
> current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/ffi-1.9.18/ext/ffi_c /usr/bin/ruby2.2 -r ./siteconf20170522-20222-maqkg4.rb extconf.rb
> ```
>
> mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at
> /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h
>
> extconf failed, exit code 1

In fact I received above error message with other ways of installing compass.

I need to install compass either locally or globally to compile `.sass` files in the project I am working on.

This is existing package.json (project was cloned from Github)

```
{
  "name": "KolosynthServices",
  "title": "Kolosynth Services",
  "description": "Kolosynth Services",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-compass": "~1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "~0.1.2",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "~0.6.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.1.1",
    "grunt-contrib-nodeunit": "~0.1.2",
    "grunt-contrib-sass": "~0.8.1",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.9.2",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.2.0",
    "matchdep": "~0.1.2"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "main": "Gruntfile.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "grunt": "^0.4.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

When I type in $ grunt inside my project's working directory I get:

> Running "compass:dist" (compass) task Warning: not found: compass Use
> --force to continue.
>
> Aborted due to warnings.

Some CLI outputs:

```
$ grunt --version => grunt-cli v1.2.0
$ ruby -v => ruby 2.2.7p470 (2017-03-28 revision 58194) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
$ gem -v => 2.6.12
$ compass -v => bash: /usr/bin/compass: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Did you manageg to get this working? In my case, running $ which compass was returning /usr/local/bin/compass . I have created a symlink to fix this.